# SPARQL query returns empty table

Tags: sparql

Hello I am new to SPARQL and I am trying to retrieve the values of the
dbo:wikiPageWikiLink Property from the followin page:
[link](https://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Grape_varieties_of_Greece)

Below is my query that unfortunately returns nothing.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Cheers!

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?link WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Grape_varieties_of_Greece> dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?link }
```

I tried also

```
SELECT ?link WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Grape_varieties_of_Greece> dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?link }
```

Comment: if you open the resource in the [browser](https://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Grape_varieties_of_Greece), you can see the "is XXX of" formulation for your property `wikiPageWikiLink` - that means, those resources are incoming edges which in fact means you have to use the resource in object position and ask for the subjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this view is telling you that your IRI is the *object* of the triple, rather than the *subject*.

[image]

Notice that it's saying that `<http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Grape_varieties_of_Greece>` *is* `dbo:wikiPageWikiLink` *of* the list.

So you can find it by running this query:

```
SELECT ?link
WHERE {
?link dbo:wikiPageWikiLink <http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Grape_varieties_of_Greece>
}
```